# Need to tackle date type '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' in Sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I am trying to tackle the errored date type '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' with a empty string in Sql & then I want to return the corrected date or the empty string in a variable. I tried the below & wanted to check if there is a better way of doing the same. Kindly help.

Note : My query is expected to return only one date value at a time. So, will there be any problem when the query value refreshes.

```
declare @v_date datetime

select @v_date = (select Date_Released from dbo.Tbl_Workstream where Loan_Number = 'XXX')

SELECT v = CASE WHEN @v_date = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'

                              THEN ''

                              ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(23), @v_date, 21)

END FROM @v_date;
```

Thanking again.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the result to be able to show an empty string, you need to use one of the string types (char, varchar, etc)

```
declare @v_date char(23);
select @v_date = CONVERT(char(23), 
          (select Date_Released from dbo.Tbl_Workstream where Loan_Number = 'XXX'), 21);
select case when @v_date = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN '' ELSE @v_Date END as V;
```